# Eclipse code formatter: spacing in empty blocks

Tags: eclipse, formatting

i configured the eclipse code formatter to display an empty block's brackets in one line. Now my projects checkstyle configuration requires spacing between these brackets. Is it possible to tell Eclipse to do this.

e.g.: `emptyMethod() { }`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to put a space between the braces with the Eclipse formatter.
As a workaround I removed the "WhitespaceAround" rule from the checkStyle plugin configuration.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Where is the "Whitespace Around" rule in the checkStyle plugin configuration exactly?

Comment: In Eclipse Preferences, choose 'Checkstyle' and configure your default Check Configuration. When you select 'Whitespace' in the tree view at the left side, you can disable the "Whitespace Around" rule on the right. (I didn't want to keep this dangling allthough it's really late...)